# Resetting a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a countdown timer for clicking a button at 0 second and it works but I want the time itself to reset after the click. Using this code I want `Time 1` to be reset when `work2` is clicked

```js
function toTimeString(seconds) {
  return (new Date(seconds * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
}

function startTimer() {
  var nextElem = $(this).parents('td').next();
  var duration = nextElem.text();
  var a = duration.split(':');
  var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
  setInterval(function() {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds >= 0) {
      nextElem.html(toTimeString(seconds));
    }
    if (seconds === 0) {
      document.getElementById('work2').click();
      clearInterval(seconds);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
$('.lazy').on('click', startTimer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 
        
<tr>
<td>
<input id="work1" class="lazy" type="button"  value="Time 1"/>
</td>
<td>:00:05</td>
</tr>


 <tr>
 <td>
 <input id="work2" class="lazy" type="button" value="Time 2" type="button" />
 </td>
 <td>:10:00</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You know that `$('.lazy').on('click', startTimer);` will start timers for both work1 and work2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers are used like this: You start the timer and store the timer handle in a variable. When stopping the timer, you hand over this variable.

```
var timer1 = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);
..
clearInterval(timer1);
```